# How can I render to image a 3D scene?

Tags: c#, 3d

my question is quite simple:
how can I create a 3D scene in c# and render it to an image?
Are there easy-to-use 3D engins or libraries that allow me to do so?

I have to realize a web-based app that let the user navigate an enviroment and I need to show him images (street-view like)

Thank you

Comment: It might be better to process this on the client side, with javascript or flash, instead of on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many fairly easy to use 3D Engines which work from C#, all of which support this, including:

- [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx)
- [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/)
- [Mogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/MOGRE)

Comment: Mogre is ok, i tried axiom before, that should be almost the same, but i was getting a NotImplementedException saving the image. Thank you!

Comment: @p4bl0: Mogre is a bit more polished than Axiom.  Axiom is a managed port - where mogre is a wrapper, so it uses the actual Ogre code (which is very, very extensively used...)

Answer (score 0):

[Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) supplies a web player. Only problem: the PRO version supports render-to-texture, but the free version doesn't.